# Inheritance: declare a method that returns the current instance class

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I have a Vector and 2-dimensional Vector, defined as follows:

```
    // A general vector
    class Vector {
        values: number[];

        constructor (...values: number[]) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        opposite(): Vector {
            return new Vector(...this.values.map((value, index) => -value));
        }
    }

    // Two-dimensional vector
    class Vector2 extends Vector {
        constructor(x: number, y: number) {
            super(x, y);
        }

        get x() {
            return this.values[0];
        }

        get y() {
            return this.values[1];
        }
    }
```

And I have the following code:

```
    let v = new Vector2(1, 2);
    let w = v.opposite();

    // this is wrong, since w is not a 2-dimensional vector
    console.log(w.x);
```

How could I solve this inheritance problem elegantly? For me, there are two alternatives:

1. Override the "opposite" method. **I think that this is not a good idea**, since currently there is only one method, but there could be a lot of them.

   ```
   // Two-dimensional vector
   class Vector2 extends Vector {
       // ... more methods ... blah blah blah ...
       // overrides the super class method
       opposite(): Vector2 {
           let [x, y] = super.opposite().values;
           return new Vector2(x, y);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a *named constructor*. I think this is a good solution, but a bit tedious:

   ```
   // Two-dimensional vector
   class Vector2 extends Vector {
       constructor(x: number, y: number) {
           super(x, y);
       }

       // declare a "named constructor"
       static createFromVector(v: Vector): Vector2 {
           let [x, y] = v.values;
           return new Vector2(x, y);
       }

       // ... more methods ... blah blah blah ...
   }

   let v = new Vector2(1, 2);
   // It's good, but a bit tedious writing constantly "createFromVector"
   let w = Vector2.createFromVector(v.opposite());
   ```

How do you address this problem?

Comment: Side note. The `Vector2` is not an two-dimensional vector. It is a vector of rank equal to 2 (since it only has 2 elements). It is still using a single-dimension JS array under the hood.

Comment: Well, it declares also two getters: x and y. It enriches the definition of a general vectors.

Comment: @Cequiel I understand that, but it is not a two-dimensional Vector. That's all I said. :)

Comment: The title of your question should indicate the *purpose* of the code, rather than what you want to gain from the review.  Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: As a side note: the elegant solution to this problem is to use a dependently-typed language.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> let v = new Vector2(1, 2);
> let w = v.opposite();
> // this is wrong, since w is not a 2-dimensional vector
> console.log(w.x);
> ```

The fact that the `.opposite()` returns a result that does not fit into the expected use cases, suggests that there is a design issue. In other words, it is a "hint" that `Vector2` is not really a `Vector` in terms of OOP. Why so? Because it does not follow the intuitive contract in which the `.opposite()` method returns *same exact type* of the vector as the one on which the method is being invoked. Things will only get worse if one will need to work against a `Vector3`, `Vector4`, etc.

There's whole [bunch of sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=composition%20over%20inheritance) that explain how inheritance is very often not the best way to create new types nor reuse code.

If I was to design the `VectorOf2`, I would make it *wrap* the `Vector` class rather than inherit from it.

```
class VectorOf2 {
    private _vector: Vector;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this._vector = new Vector(x, y);
    }

    get x(): number {
        return this._vector[0];
    }

    get y(): number {
        return this._vector[1];
    }

    opposite(): VectorOf2 {
        return new VectorOf2( ... );
    }
}
```

With this design, each method added to `Vector2` is always `Vector2`-specific and there's no confusion about it. The regular `Vector`'s method can still be reused by `VectorOf2` when a new method is implemented.